# Android calendar view scrollable

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar, calendarview

I want to make the calendar view to display 2 months, one on top of the other and to be able to scroll/swipe down/up to move between months.
like in the attached image[image]

I tired different custom calendar view but could not find anything like that.

(I just want to make sure there is definitely nothing like that before I start making it myself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

it called CalendarListview. here is a link :

https://github.com/traex/CalendarListview

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's One more:

https://github.com/ik024/CalendarLibrary

[image] [image]

Hope it helps.